# Trouble deleting a record using PHP. Code included

Tags: php, mysql

I Have simple PHP functions that produce html links which should delete a record, however the delete link only manages to refresh the page.

I know the solution is simple but I am new to PHP so could somebody please be kind enough to point me in the right direction? thank you. help greatly appreciated.

fuctions.php

```
<?php
     include('includes/connect.php'); 
  function getPosts() {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts") or die(mysql_error());
        while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $post['Title'] . "</td><td>" . $post['Author'] . "</td><td><a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $post['ID'] . "\">Delete</a><br /><a href=\"edit.php>?id=" . $post['ID'] . "\">Edit</a></td></tr>";
        }
    }
    function deletePost($id) {
        $id = (int) $id;
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE ID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
        header("Location: posts.php");
  }
?>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
   include('includes/functions.php');
   deletePost($_GET['ID']);
?>
```

Comment: you don't pass parameter called `ID` to your script.

Comment: deletePost($_GET['id']); case sensitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `delete.php` file, you call:

```
deletePost($_GET['ID']);
```

However, in your link you use:

```
delete.php?id=
```

It is a case issue, make them both be upper case `ID` or lower case `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your casing.

You are setting the `GET` paramets name to `id` while checking for `ID`

Answer (score 0):

Print your sql delete command before executing and it I suppose will answer your question.